# How to round a number up in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can a number be rounded up to the nearest whole number in Flutter?

- 0.1 => 1
- 1.5 => 2
- -0.1 => -1

The Num `round` methods rounds to the nearest integer. How can one always round up?

Comment: `-0.1 => -1` is not "rounding up".  "Rounding up" means "toward positive infinity". What you're asking for is to round away from zero.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To round up to the nearest whole number in an absolute sense, use `ceil` if the number is positive and `floor` if the number is smaller than 0.

The following function rounds numbers up to the closest integer.

```
static int roundUpAbsolute(double number) {
  return number.isNegative ? number.floor() : number.ceil();
}
```

Or, use an extension function (`6.3.roundUpAbs`).

```
extension Round on double {
  int get roundUpAbs => this.isNegative ? this.floor() : this.ceil();
}
```

Comment: This answer rounds all doubles correctly. `-0.1` is rounded to `-1`. Your answer does not round double variables correctly.

Answer (score 32):

You can use the `.ceil()` method to achieve what you want.

Example:

```
print(-0.1.ceil()); => -1
```

```
print(1.5.ceil()); => 2
```

```
print(0.1.ceil()); => 1
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect as well.
`double number = -0.1; number.ceil() => 0`. While `-0.1.ceil()` rounds to `-1`, the `ceil` method seems to round the number first and then applies the sign. This is likely why `ceil` is incorrect if the number is variable which encompasses the sign.